# SBT, Run a main class from dependency project

Tags: scala, sbt

My build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += "org" %% "A" % "0.0.1"
```

So I run sbt on this file:

```
> sbt
```

I know that there is Main class in 'A', let's say "mainRun.scala". But I don't how to run it from my project.

How should I run it from SBT?

Comment: Have you tried `> runMain mainRun`? If that works you can probably set it up to work by default on `> run` with this sbt setting: `mainClass := Some("mainRun")`.

Comment: thanks it worked, please put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, sbt does not look into your dependencies for the auto detection of a main class. You can can however force it to use a specific class, either on the command line with

```
> runMain pack.MainClass
```

or via the sbt setting

```
mainClass := Some("pack.MainClass")
```